# How can I change the font after "," in string

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I have a string value containing an amount, where I specified the decimal part as after "," and I want to change the font of the part after "," to be half of the other part

```
private func getText(text: String, size: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(
        string: text,
        attributes: [
            .font: UIFont.themeFont(ofSize: size, weight: .medium)
        ]
    )
    
    if let commaRange = text.range(of: ",") {
        let startIndex = text.index(commaRange.upperBound, offsetBy: 1)
        let substring = text[startIndex...]
        
        attributedString.addAttributes(
            [
                .font: UIFont.themeFont(ofSize: size / 2, weight: .medium)
            ],
            range: NSRange(location: text.distance(from: text.startIndex, to: startIndex), length: substring.count)
        )
    }
    
    return attributedString
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
private func getText(text: String, size: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString {
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    let comaRange = (text as NSString).range(of: ",")
    let afterComaRange = NSRange(location: comaRange.location  + 1 , length: text.count - comaRange.location - 1)
    let font = UIFont.themeFont(ofSize: size, weight: .medium)
    let changedFont = UIFont.themeFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .medium)
    attributedText.addAttribute(.font, value: font, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: comaRange.location))
    attributedText.addAttribute(.font, value: changedFont, range: afterComaRange)
    return attributedText
}
```

this is my answer and it's work.

Answer (score 0):

The `upperbound` of a range is the index **after** the index of the last character in the range, so the offset is not needed.

The `substring` is not needed either, and use the `addAttribute(_:value:range:)` API to apply **one** attribute

```
private func getText(text: String, size: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(
        string: text,
        attributes: [
            .font: UIFont.themeFont(ofSize: size, weight: .medium)
        ]
    )
    
    if let commaRange = text.range(of: ",") {
        let nsRange = NSRange(commaRange.upperBound..., in: text)
        attributedString.addAttribute(.font,
                                      value: UIFont.themeFont(ofSize: size / 2, weight: .medium),
                                      range: nsRange)
    }
    return attributedString
}
```

Or determine the range with Regex

```
private func getText(text: String, size: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(
        string: text,
        attributes: [
            .font: UIFont.themeFont(ofSize: size, weight: .medium)
        ]
    )

    if let match = text.firstMatch(of: /,(\d+)/) {
        let nsRange = NSRange(match.output.1.startIndex..., in: text)
        attributedString.addAttribute(.font,
                                      value: UIFont.themeFont(ofSize: size / 2, weight: .medium),
                                      range: nsRange)
    }
    return attributedString
}
```

A still more convenient way is Swift's native `AttributedString`

```
func getText(text: String, size: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString {
    var attributedString = AttributedString(text)
    attributedString.font = UIFont.themeFont(ofSize: size, weight: medium)
    if let range = attributedString.characters.firstRange(of: ",") {
        attributedString[range.upperBound...].font = UIFont.themeFont(ofSize: size/2, weight: .medium)
    }
    return NSAttributedString(attributedString)
}
```

Side note: Converting `Range<String.Index>` to `NSRange` with `NSRange(location:length:)` is strongly discouraged.

Comment: One should never, ever assume that a character is one unit. Your code is correctly written and will work with characters that are more than one unit long, and also with strings that are not single characters, say if you want to make a change after the first "::".

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be fun to provide a solution using modern Swift. Attributed strings are now native (AttributedString). Regular expressions are now native (Regex). So we can write it like this:

```
func getText(text: String, size: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString {
    var result = AttributedString(text)
    result.font = UIFont.themeFont(
        ofSize: size, weight: .medium
    )
    if let regex = try? Regex("(,)(?<postcomma>.*)$"),
       let match = try? regex.firstMatch(in: text),
       let range = match["postcomma"]?.range,
       let attributedRange = Range(range, in: result) {
        result[attributedRange].font = UIFont.themeFont(
            ofSize: size/2, weight: .medium
        )
    }
    return NSAttributedString(result)
}
```